# Boostrap navbar getting half hidden on mobile device on scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap navbar with fixed position.

`<nav class="navbar navbar-light fixed-top background-00" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(247, 247, 247);height: 65px;"></nav>`

Its working fine in responsive mode.

Now when i enable mobile view in chrome & scroll , the navbar gets half hidden.

How to keep it fixed on mobile also ?

[image: Before scroll]

[image: After scroll]

Answer (score 0):

Have you put this line in `<head>` of your html?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Can you post a clearer image of what your problem exactly is? Like I cannot see much difference in both the pictures

Comment: In first image the Progress is in middle of header (Which is expected), but when i scroll down (IInd image) the header scroll above (Progress is sticking to top). This is happening only when mobile view is enabled. If i resize window and mobile view is off this is working fine.